# Moving embedded youtube iframe in dom with jquery causes fullscreen to not work in Windows8 IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am trying to move the contents of one div and append it to another div. The div that I am moving includes a embedded youtube iframe. When I try clicking on the full screen button after the div has been moved, the video resets instead of continuing playback in full screen. The same issue happens if I move the iframe itself to another location.

Here's an example:

```
$(iframes).each(function() {
    $('.tab_content').append($(this));
});
```

After moving the embedded iframes, in Windows 8 IE10, I can't view the video in full screen.

Reloading the iframe also doesn't seem to be fixing the bug:

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', '');
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in jsfiddle so people can try them selves?

Answer (score 4):

you can use this method.

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
    $('.tab_content').append($(this).prop('outerHTML'));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What if you clone the iframe?

```
$(iframes).each(function() {
    $('.tab_content').append($(this).clone());
});
```